# Javascript - How do i stop the execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my link with embedded js

```
<a style="padding: 5px;" onclick="confirm_message(); $('contact_693_').show(); $('errors_693_').hide(); this.hide(); $('dont_693_').show();; return false;" id="the_link_693_" href="#" class="add_someone_else">Check it out</a>
```

And here is my function

```
function confirm_message(){
         var response = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(response){
      return false;
    }else{
             return false;
        }
}
```

Basically I dont want any of the other js to fire if the user clicks no in the confirm....but all the other javascript

```
  $('contact_693_').show(); $('errors_693_').hide(); this.hide(); $('dont_693_').show();; return false;"
```

still fires whether the user clicks yes or no in the confirm...any ideas on how to fix this....

Also this embedded js was not created by me and is built on the page with ruby...

Comment: Can you post the ruby code that produces this? Is it Rails?

Answer (score 3):

Throw an error, like this:

```
function confirm_message(){
    var response = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(response){
      return false;
    }else{
         throw new Error("Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked your JS, sorry."); // or something a little more descriptive
    }
}
```

It's not pretty but it should stop all future JS from processing.

Comment: how would throwing an error help the user....i just want the box to close and the other js not to fire.

Comment: @Matt: Throwing an error will cause all other Javascript on the page to cease executing. That includes 'the other js'.

Answer (score 2):

Include your code in the confirm function:

```
function confirm_then_execute(){    
     var response = confirm("Are you sure?");    
     if(response){
         $('contact_693_').show(); $('errors_693_').hide();this.hide(); $('dont_693_').show();return false;"
     }
     else{    
         return false;    
    }
}
```

html:

```
<a style="padding: 5px;" onclick="confirm_then_execute()" id="the_link_693_" href="#" class="add_someone_else">Check it out</a>
```

Comment: i cant do that because i dont have those div ids and class on the js level

Comment: How about passing the ids as arguments: confirm_then_execute(id1,id2)?